# Столб или столп?

Tags: этимология, лексика

Как правильно говорить "столб" или "столп" и чем отличаются эти слова?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Столп" - устаревшая форма слова "столб". В настоящее время слово "столп" употребляется для обозначения архитектурных сооружений в виде колонны, а также ярких личностей своего времени ("Они - столпы в науке").

Answer (score -1):

Столп - колонна, в которой жили подвижники (столпники).
Столб - просто колонна.